# Does time_t exist in JNA?

Tags: jna, unix-timestamp, time-t

I downloaded Java Native Access in Eclipse for use in a program, specifically to use a variable **time_t date** in order to get a unix timestamp. Does that structure exist, or is it in another form?

In case it doesn't exist, what would be my best alternative to get time to just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: What native functions are you trying to use?  That has a large bearing on the "best" way to get unix epoch time and what type to use to represent it.

Answer (score 0):

JNA does not have a specific type for `time_t` because it's usually easily modeled on any particular operating system by an existing primitive type.

You can define one yourself easily... on macOS you could just replace it with a `NativeLong` or use:

```
class time_t extends IntegerType { 
    public time_t() { 
        super(Native.LONG_SIZE); 
    } 
}
```

Since [time_t is defined in seconds](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html), you could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` if 
you divided it by 1000.  It all depends on what use you have for the variable. Generally if you're using JNA you're trying to use some native time value.